# RxJava2 - Emit onError on parallel rail will get UndeliverableException

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Although one of the rail is emitted `onError()`, `isCancelled()` in another rails is still return false, that lead to the `UndeliverableException`. How to check downstream is cancelled in parallel rails?

```
Disposable disposable = Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<Integer> emitter) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Flowable.create-emitter.isCancelled:" + emitter.isCancelled());
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            emitter.onNext(i);
        }
        emitter.onComplete();
    }

}, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER).parallel(6).runOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(new Function<Integer, Publisher<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Publisher<String> apply(Integer t) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
                            System.out.println("flatMap-before onError-isCancelled:" + emitter.isCancelled());
                            try {
                                if (true) { // assume trigger the error
                                    throw new Exception("Test");
                                }
                                if (!emitter.isCancelled()) {
                                    emitter.onNext(String.valueOf((t + 1)));
                                    emitter.onComplete();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                if (!emitter.isCancelled()) {
                                    emitter.onError(ex);
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("flatMap-after onError-isCancelled:" + emitter.isCancelled());
                    }
                }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
            }

        }).sequential().subscribeOn(scheduler).observeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .subscribeWith(new ResourceSubscriber<String>() {

            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("onComplete");

            }

            public void onError(Throwable arg0) {
                System.out.println("onError:" + arg0.toString());

            }

            public void onNext(String arg0) {
                System.out.println("onNext:" + arg0);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I need add a global error consumer to solve the problem.
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling

Answer (score 0):

The instant you call `onError()` the entire downstream observer chain will finish up. You cannot do `onNext()`, `onError()`, or `onComplete()` afterwards because there is nothing to deliver to. That is called the "reactive contract".

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know the rule, I emit `onNext()` and `onComplete()` after `onError()` is for some testing. I edited the code to comply with the rule, but the problem still exist